# ShowDialog property for MDI winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, mdichild

**Question:**

How do I display a MDI child form in a ShowDialog() format?

**What I've tried:**

```
private void Add()
        {

            ModuleAddPopUp map = new ModuleAddPopUp();
            map.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            map.ShowDialog();          
        }
```

Doing the above, the form displays center screen as a pop-up, however I can drag the form outside the MDI when the MDI isn't maximized.

```
private void Add()
        {
            ModuleAddPopUp map = new ModuleAddPopUp();
            FormFunctions.OpenMdiDataForm(App.Program.GetMainMdiParent(), map);

        }
```

Doing the above, the form displays center screen, doesn't allow for the form to be dragged outside the MDI, but acts as a map.Show() , rather than a map.ShowDialog();

Comment: So you want to display a fixed centered from?

Comment: Yes.  When my add form is displayed, all other forms can't be interacted with until I'm done with the child form, and should be centered in the MDI parent.  (The form where my add function is in above).

Comment: And you want to prevent the user from moving the form?

Comment: As long as it doesn't go outside the MDI .

Comment: There's just no point to this, users just don't care that the dialog is not constrained by the parent bounds.  They can't interact with the MDI windows anyway.  In fact, they *prefer* it this way.  Makes it much easier to take a peek at the underlying windows for any relevant info that helps them complete the dialog.

Comment: Yeah, when I wrote my question, I thought part of my requirements were it had to be bounded, but after verification , it didn't.  It just has to be in a ShowDialog form in the MDI, which works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code to your `ModuleAddPopup` class:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
    const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    const int SC_MOVE = 0xF010;
    //SC_SIZE = 0XF000 if you also want to prevent them from resizing the form.
    //Add it to the 'if' condition.
    switch (message.Msg)
    {
        case WM_SYSCOMMAND:
            int command = message.WParam.ToInt32() & 0xfff0;
            if (command == SC_MOVE)
                return;
            break;
    }

    base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```

This is native code wrapped in C# code, as seen in [here](https://vaibhavgaikwad.wordpress.com/2006/06/05/creating-a-immovable-windows-form-in-c/).
This, however, will prevent the user from moving the dialog form anywhere.

Then, in your main form:

```
private void Add()
{
    ModuleAddPopUp map = new ModuleAddPopUp();
    map.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    map.ShowDialog();          
}
```